# PropertyWrapper - Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage

Tags: swift, properties, combine

I'm working with `Property wrappers` in a project that is divided into few `Swift package` modules dependent on each others. I have been using my own property wrappers in the code, but I want to switch to `Combine`, as it contains a lot of similar functionalities to my own `property wrappers`. In the process of converting I often occur the compiler issue:

`Abort trap: 6` with error message: `Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!`.

As the first step I have decided to get rid of this error while still using my own `property wrappers`, because it can occur even there, but I managed to get rid of it. But in not a clean way, and I would like to get more knowledge on what is going on, so I could proceed with `Combine` later - with the same errors.

Ok, so to get rid of the `Abort trap: 6` with my old `property wrappers` I needed to switch the way I used this property in some of modules. Instead of writing and reading it directly, I access it with $property.wrappedValue. Then it works, but this is very ugly in code, and kinda denies the puropse of using a `property wrapper`. Could someone explain me why this error occurs? In some of the modules Im able to use it directly with no problem. I have no idea what is going on, and what I can do to resolve this. I tried to convert a lot of similar properties with `Combine`, and I just get more of this errors, and actually I was not even able to resolve them like this.

Please tell me what is this error about, why it happens and what I can do to resolve it.
[image]

If his helps, this is how this property wrapper is defined:

```
@propertyWrapper
public class ObservableChangedValue<Value: Equatable>: Observable<Value> {

    public var projectedValue: ObservableChangedValue { self }

    public override var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { super.wrappedValue }
        set { super.wrappedValue = newValue }
    }

    override func shouldExecuteNotifications(oldValue: Value, newValue: Value) -> Bool {
        oldValue != newValue
    }

}

public class Observable<Value> {

    public init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
    }

    internal var observations = [Observation<Value>]() { didSet { isBeingObserved = !observations.isEmpty } }

    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        didSet {
            guard shouldExecuteNotifications(oldValue: oldValue, newValue: wrappedValue) else { return }
            observations.forEach {
                $0.executeNotification(oldValue: oldValue, newValue: wrappedValue)
            }
        }
    }

    public weak var delegate: ObservableDelegate?

    public var isBeingObserved = false {
        didSet {
            guard isBeingObserved != oldValue else { return }
            delegate?.isBeingObservedChanged(isBeingObserved)
        }
    }

    internal func shouldExecuteNotifications(oldValue: Value, newValue: Value) -> Bool { true }

}
```

One big thing - I have noticed that the error only occurs when I access this variable from other file than where it was defined. I added getters and setters for now, but still not a nice solution. This seems to be a compiler error, but Im not sure.

Comment: Seems over the top, since ObservableObject already exists (not to mention simple `@Published` and even simpler Subject).

Comment: Yep, as I have mentioned the next step is to get rid of this and use Combine instead. I was doing that and in the process I get the same errors - Abort trap 6. This is why I’m trying to understand this error and know how to avoid it later when converting to Combine.

Comment: Well I think you might be optimizing prematurely. :) Convert to Combine and then discover there’s no issue. You didn’t show any Combine code.

Comment: There is :) that’s the point. I was concerting the whole code to Published and then I get the same errors. Anyway I think I have found some trace. Using property wrappers in extensions from different file seems to be causing this. I will try again avoiding using different files for extensions.

Comment: Ooooo that could be downright useful to know. Makes sense intuitively too.

Answer (score -1):

> Using property wrappers in extensions from different file seems to be
>   causing this

see what they claims in documentation

Property wrapper types

A property wrapper type is a type that can be used as a property wrapper. There are two basic requirements for a property wrapper type:

1. The property wrapper type must be defined with the attribute
   @propertyWrapper. The attribute indicates that the type is meant to
   be used as a property wrapper type, and provides a point at which
   the compiler can verify any other consistency rules.
2. The property wrapper type must have **a property named wrappedValue,
   whose access level is the same as that of the type itself**. This is
   the property used by the compiler to access the underlying value on
   the wrapper instance.